# How to use a switch statement on a random number generator in Java?

Tags: java, random

I'm in a intro to java course, and part of my assignment is to make the card game War. I used a random number generator to randomly generate a number for the rank of the card, and the suit. I wanted to know how to use the switch statement to change it to two words like Ace Spades or Jack hearts etc....

```
final int CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13;
final int SUIT = 4;

System.out.print(ran.nextInt(CARDS_IN_SUIT) + 1 + " ");
System.out.println(ran.nextInt(SUIT) + 1);
System.out.print(ran.nextInt(CARDS_IN_SUIT) + 1 + " ");
System.out.println(ran.nextInt(SUIT) + 1 + " " );
```

That's what I have so far. I don't have to use a switch statement, any way of changing the int to a string would be helpful.

Comment: CAn you explain your problem in a better way? What exactly do you want?

Comment: You'll have to use two switches and evaluate the card number and suit separately unless you don't want to go insane. Also don't worry, a switch is suited to this kind of thing. Pun intended!

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
final String[] cardsArray = {
    "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
    "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Jack",
    "Queen", "King", "Ace"
};

final String[] suitArray = {
    "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs" 
};

final int CARDS_IN_SUIT = cardsArray.length;
final int SUIT = suitArray.length;

System.out.print(cardsArray[ran.nextInt(CARDS_IN_SUIT)] + " ");
System.out.println(suitArray[ran.nextInt(SUIT)]);
System.out.print(cardsArray[ran.nextInt(CARDS_IN_SUIT)] + " ");
System.out.println(suitArray[ran.nextInt(SUIT)] + " " );
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the values of `ran.nextInt() + 1` in two `int` variables. These will be the variables you can switch on. Then you can initialize two strings, calling them `rank` and `suit`. Finally, you can use a switch statement to assign to the strings as follows:

```
int randomRank = ran.nextInt(CARDS_IN_SUIT) + 1;
int randomSuit = ran.nextInt(SUIT) + 1;
String rank;
String suit;
switch (randomRank) {
    case 1:  rank = "Ace";
             break;
    case 2:  rank = "Two";
             break;
    .
    .
    .
    case 13: rank = "King";
             break;
    default: rank = "???"
             break;
}
switch(randomSuit) {
    case 1: suit = "Spades";
            break;
    .
    .
    .
    default: suit = "???";
             break;
}
```

Finally, you have two strings, one containing the rank, and another containing the suit. You can print them using `System.out`.

The switches will take some time to write out and complete so I will leave that to you. I hope this helps you out.